# DNS/DHCP/MAC Address

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, dhcp

I was wondering if anyone knew how to configure either a server 2003/2008 server or bind to hand out the same ip address to a machine by its mac address via DHCP?

Comment: If "bind" is in fact [ISC BIND](http://www.isc.org/software/bind), it cannot do what you need it to do, because it's a DNS server and not a DHCP server.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its a language barrier, but your question is oddly phrased. BIND is a DNS daemon and has nothing to do with DHCP. If you wish to setup a Windows based DHCP server, please read the following:

http://www.petri.co.il/almost-everything-you-need-to-know-about-dhcp-as-a-systems-administrator.htm?wp7=1&theme=&accent=

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756865(WS.10).aspx

This is not difficult and taking some time to read you should be able to execute it shortly thereafter. If you need this DHCP server to service network segments it is not connected to please update your post as more information will be required to answer that.

I would also add that the technique you're referring to, making sure that a specific machine gets a specific address via MAC address is called "Address reservation".